# simple email function not working

Tags: php, html, email

I have write this code in my live site .

```
$to = "samplmail@gmail.com";
$subject = "sample";
$message = "hiiiiiiiiiii";
$from = "samplmail@yahoo.com";
$headers = "From: " .$from. "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $to. "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if( $mail ) {
   echo "mail sent";
} else {
   echo "mail not sent";
}
```

But it print "mail not sent".
ANd i didnt receive any email too. please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Are you working on localhost?

Comment: its working fine @my side..if u want to test ur mails on localhost u can test it by: http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/

Comment: As always when php inside a http server does not what you expect: take a look into the log files! Everything else is fishing in the dark and guessing what might happen. Most likely your php setup simply does not define a working mail transport.

Comment: are you using linux server?

Comment: is 'sendmail' installed?

Comment: try the command "dpkg -s sendmail"

Answer (score 1):

You should consider to use https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer.

This is just simple example successful code I often use in my applications:

```
<?php
include('class/class.phpmailer.php');

$subject = "Your subject here";
$message = "<p>HTML Email message</p>";

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->AddReplyTo("your_email_from@example.com","Your Name");
$mail->SetFrom("your_email_from@example.com","Your Name");
$mail->AddAddress("customer_email@gmail.com", "Customer Name");
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$mail->Send();
?>
```

If using that code still not working, then you should ask to your hosting provider about this issue.

Comment: why not the right repository https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer ? PHPMailer is good because you can easily use it with STMP, POP3, Mail, Sendmail and Qmail

Comment: @maswid I have tried with that files. But still not working. I have contacted server people. They give me access to c panel. And they told me to activate email configration . How to enable that

Comment: most of hosting providers allow us to send email trough PHP mailer, even if you never set email configuration. I think it's about enabling php mailer on your hosting server. And they can do that for you. So the next answer to your hosting provider is "Can you help me enabling PHP Mailer please?" .. :-)